# Embed Youtube Video in R Markdown

Tags: r, html, youtube, r-markdown, video-embedding

I am trying to publish a `.Rmd` in [Rpubs](http://rpubs.com) by embedding a YouTube video link. After some exploration, I am trying the following which just gives a blank space in my html.

```
<div align="center">
   <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/zsYjsgm4Psg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

Two related posts:

1. [rmarkdown: Alter Action Depending on Document](http://www.r-bloggers.com/rmarkdown-alter-action-depending-on-document/)
2. [R markdown Embedded Youtube Video](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203570516-R-markdown-Embedded-Youtube-Video-)

Comment: Any trouble using this format? <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>  ?

Comment: I am still getting a black space in my html.

Comment: Could you provide the link to Rpubs? Then others could check whether they can see the video.

Comment: I also got a blank space when I knit the html. The video only appeared when I clicked on 'Open in Browser' in the generated html document (using RStudio).

Answer (score 14):

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/9bZkp7q19f0?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This can optionally be put inside a code chunk within your `.Rmd`

[Source](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~lcollado/misc/video_in_beamer/video_in_report.Rmd)

Comment: Why would you put the HTML code in an code chunk? For me it works, if I simply put the HTML line in an `.Rmd` file. Publishing on Rpubs worked as well.

Comment: @Stibu you don't strictly have to put it in a chunk, the original author did that as a matter of style for presenting it.

Answer (score 1):

On you tube, I tried using the link for sharing, https://youtu.be/....

But instead find "embed" under where you tube gives the share link. This give the  tag you need and the right link, it is not the same has you would use in an  tag.